# Прокрутка listview при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, требуется чтобы при нажатии на кнопку снизу списка listview происходил скролл вниз к конкретному элементу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть метод у ListView smoothScrollToPosition. На вход принимает позицию, к которой нужно проскролить. Например:

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
list.smoothScrollToPosition(21);
```

В данном примере, происходит плавный скрол к элементу с позицией 21.
Только добавьте этот код в обработчик клика для кнопки и готово.

Comment: Либо `list.setSelection(21);` для моментального скрола.